# How to concatenate WAV files in C#

Tags: c#, merge, wav

I have 2 wav files that I want to concatenate into one file with the two sound tracks.

Is there any api for that task or some built in commands in .NET that can I can use in some genius way to make this task possible?

Many thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Can you just clarify that you want to merge the two tracks so they play synchronously, or do you want to append one track to the end of the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you can just append the bytes from the second file to the end of the first. If there is any header data, you'll want to exclude that (see [here](http://filext.com/file-extension/WAV))

Be advised that you may hear a click or pop between the two clips, as there will be no blending. You could probably get around this by fading (gradually reducing the values for the last few ms to the center value).

Comment: This does not work as the players dont pick up on the new time for the wav file

Answer (score 3):

If you only need to do this once then your best bet is to use some software specifically for the task. [Praat](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/) or [audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) will do this (join or merge two tracks).

Praat can also be scripted so it is possible to script Praat and then call Praat and the script from within a .Net application.

Rob

Comment: hum :) 

Yes, I know that, the problem is that I have like 60 files  files that need to be combined into 15 minutes files. And most likely do I have to do this more than once. 

I have had a look at sox and mancoder as an example of what you are telling but they don't seem to to the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot *merely* append one file (sans the 44 byte header) to the other as others suggested. The header defines not just the size of the data but the sample rate, channel count, and bit depth. If the audio format is precisely the same between the two files, however, you *could* append if you also update the headers in the two places that depend on the size.

[This site](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422-winter-2014/projects/WaveFormat/) provides a good low-level descrpition of the format from which you can identify what parts of the header you'd need to change. Again assuming the audio formats are identical you'd need to update the chunk size at byte offset 4, and the Subchunk2Size at byte offset 40. Basically just add to each of the existing values the size of the 2nd file (less 44). Then append the data from the 2nd file (at offset 44) to the first.

Now, if the audio formats are not identical (remember, even the sample rates must match) you will need to resample the second file to match the format of the first, and output a totally new WAV file with the combined data. To do this you will likely want to use an A/V library such as [FFMpegCore](https://github.com/rosenbjerg/FFMpegCore) for C#. While the math for resampling simple PCM audio data is *not* that complicated, it's tedious and will be error prone if you're not experienced. The upside is that once you master a library like FFMpeg you will be able to do literally anything imaginable with multimedia, so it's worth the investment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ConcatenatingSampleProvider of [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) package.

```cs
var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\son1.wav", FileMode.Open);
var fs2 = new FileStream(@"C:\son2.wav", FileMode.Open);
      
var reader = new WaveFileReader(fs);
var reader2 = new WaveFileReader(fs2);
var sample1 = reader.ToSampleProvider();
var sample2 = reader2.ToSampleProvider();
var sample3 = new ISampleProvider[] { sample1, sample2 };
var conc = new ConcatenatingSampleProvider(sample3);
WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile16(@"C:\son3.wav", conc);
var sound = new SoundPlayer(@"C:\son3.wav");
sound.Play();
reader.Close();
reader2.Close();
fs.Close();
fs2.Close();
```

Comment: If you would use two `using`s, you could remove the last four lines, plus your could is more exception-safe.

Answer (score -1):

The straightforward way would be to interpret the wav file headers, extract the samples and interleave the samples from both files into a new sample stream which you write to a new wav file. You could also add the sample values of both source wav files sample by sample to 'mix' both files into a single track.
The wav file format is not that complicated so it should not be too difficult to write this code. Also, there are lots of open source projects containing code to read and write wav files.
Note that things can get somewhat trickier of both source wav files have different sample rates.
Check [this](http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/WAVE.html) for a description of the wav format.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can just append the data of the second wav ( excluding its headers) as sais Jon B, but you must also modify the header of the first file to indicate the new length, otherwise some audio players will stop at the end of the first part.

For dynamic concatenation, as you don't know the size of the total wav at the beginning, you can put a fake length on the header of the first file, like put a duration of 10hours for example.

Then the audio player should just wait till you append each data. It works for ffmpeg at least